# How to do pagination in my jsp pages

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, pagination

I have two `jsp` pages.One is `searchData.jsp` and another one is `searchResult.jsp`.

searchData.jsp

```
<form action="searchResult.jsp" method="POST">
                    <table border="0" width="" cellspacing="15" cellpadding="1">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Search Using:</th>
                                <th><select name="search">
                                        <option value="Company_Name">Company Name</option>
                                        <option value="Contact_Person">Contact Person</option>
                                        <option value="Phone">Phone Number</option>
                                    </select></th>
                                <th>of Category:</th>
                                <th><select name="category">
                                        <option value="hospital"><bean:message key="select.hospital" /></option>
                                        <option value="company"><bean:message key="select.company" /></option>
                                        <option value="institution"><bean:message key="select.institution" /></option>
                                        <option value="others"><bean:message key="select.other" /></option>
                                    </select></th>
                                <th><input type="text" name="search_tf" /></th>
                                <th><input type="submit" value="Search" /></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                            <td><small>(Blank Search will result in Full Search Result)</small></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
```

when i will select *company name* and *company* and click on *submit* it will go to `searchResult.jsp` and it will display but my problem is i have 30 to 40 records in it and i have to put 10 records per page.So here pagination is necessary,i have tried using `javascript` and `jquery` but i am not getting correct pagination.Here is my code for `searchResult.jsp`

searchResult.jsp

```
<form method="post" name="form">
 <table class="divtable" width="1140">
 <div id="divheader">
<thead>
   <tr>
   <th style="padding:1px 5px;border-right:1px solid #d47f66;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;background: beige;">Id</th>
   <th style="padding:1px 5px;border-right:1px solid #d47f66;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;background: beige;">Date & Time</th>
   <th style="padding:1px 5px;border-right:1px solid #d47f66;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;background: beige;">Company Name</th>
   <th style="padding:1px 5px;border-right:1px solid #d47f66;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;background: beige;">Contact Person</th>
   <th style="padding:1px 5px;border-right:1px solid #d47f66;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;background: beige;">Address</th>
   <th style="padding:1px 5px;border-right:1px solid #d47f66;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;background: beige;">Phone</th>
   <th style="padding:1px 5px;border-right:1px solid #d47f66;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;background: beige;">Company Email</th>
   <th style="padding:1px 5px;border-right:1px solid #d47f66;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;background: beige;">Follow Up Action</th>
   <th style="padding:1px 5px;border-right:1px solid #d47f66;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;background: beige;">Status</th>
   <th style="padding:1px 5px;border-right:1px solid #d47f66;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;background: beige;">Lead Details</th>
   <th style="padding:1px 5px;border-right:1px solid #d47f66;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;background: beige;">Lead Value</th>
   <th style="padding:1px 5px;border-right:1px solid #d47f66;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;background: beige;">Follow Up Date</th>
   <th style="padding:1px 5px;border-right:1px solid #d47f66;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;background: beige;">Category</th>
   <th colspan="2" style="padding:1px 5px;border-right:1px solid #d47f66;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;background: beige;">Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    </div>
    <%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
    <%
    Connection con = null;
    Object o2 = session.getAttribute("email");
    String email = o2.toString();
    String category = request.getParameter("category");
    String search = request.getParameter("search");
    String search_tf = request.getParameter("search_tf");
    Statement st, st1;
    try {
                                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/marketing_database", "root", "root");
  st = con.createStatement();
  st1 = con.createStatement();
  System.out.println("At SearchResult.jsp:" + email + "," + category + "," + search + "," + search_tf);
  ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select Id,Company_name,Contact_Person,Address,Phone,Company_Email,Review,Status,Lead_Date,Lead_Details,Lead_Value,followup_Date,Category from marketing_database.lead where Email = '" + email + "' OR " + search + " LIKE '%" + search_tf + "%' ORDER BY Id;");
  String q2 = "update dummy set category='" + category + "' where id = '1';";
  st1.executeUpdate(q2);                    // To insert the category name to dummy table in database
%>

  <%
  while (rs.next()) {
  %>
  <tr><td style="padding:1px 5px;border-right:1px solid #d47f66;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;" class="td1"><%=rs.getString(1)%></td>
  <td style="padding:1px 5px;border-right:1px solid #d47f66;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;" class="td3"><%=rs.getString(9)%></td>
  <td style="padding:1px 5px;border-right:1px solid #d47f66;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;" class="td2"><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
   <td style="padding:1px 5px;border-right:1px solid #d47f66;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;" class="td3"><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
   <td style="padding:1px 5px;border-right:1px solid #d47f66;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;" class="td4"><%=rs.getString(4)%></td>
   <td style="padding:1px 5px;border-right:1px solid #d47f66;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;" class="td5"><%=rs.getString(5)%></td>
   <td style="padding:1px 5px;border-right:1px solid #d47f66;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;" class="td6"><%=rs.getString(6)%></td>
   <td style="padding:1px 5px;border-right:1px solid #d47f66;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;" class="td7"><%=rs.getString(7)%></td>
   <td style="padding:1px 5px;border-right:1px solid #d47f66;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;" class="td8"><%=rs.getString(8)%></td>
   <td style="padding:1px 5px;border-right:1px solid #d47f66;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;" class="td9"><%=rs.getString(10)%></td>
   <td style="padding:1px 5px;border-right:1px solid #d47f66;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;" class="td10"><%=rs.getString(11)%></td>
   <td style="padding:1px 5px;border-right:1px solid #d47f66;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;" class="td11"><%=rs.getString(12)%></td>
   <td style="padding:1px 5px;border-right:1px solid #d47f66;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;" class="td12"><%=rs.getString(13)%></td>
   <td style="padding:1px 5px;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;" class="td13"><input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" style="background-color:#49743D;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;" onclick="editRecord(<%= rs.getString(1)%>);" ></td>
   <td style="padding:1px 5px;border-right:1px solid #d47f66;border-bottom:1px solid #d47f66;" class="td13"><input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete" style="background-color:#ff0000;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;" onclick="deleteRecord(<%= rs.getString(1)%>);" ></td>
                                        <% count++;%>
                                </tr>

                                <%
                                    }
                                %>
                                <%
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                %>
                            </table>
                        </form>
```

Comment: I have tried using javascript and jquery but i am not getting correct pagination?

Comment: If you are just displaying html table, why dont you use  data tables. They have default pagination feature

Comment: hope this link help for you:http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/jsp/pagination-in-servlet-and-jsp/

Comment: @NamanGala when i searched in Google there i found some examples using javascript and jquery,i tried those but i am not getting pagination

Comment: jqgrid comes with pagination and it's useful, check their demo [here](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/)